# Emacs with Tramp mode

Tags: emacs, tramp

After doing TONS of research on every stack overflow question there is and every page that google pulls up on the subject, I am unable to get sudo to work in Emacs with Tramp mode. (Yes, I have read all the 'duplicate' questions here on stack overflow and none of the solutions work for me.)

Using Emacs 24.5.1 with the following configuration.

```
(use-package tramp
    :config (progn (setq tramp-default-proxies-alist (quote ((".*" "\'root\'" "/ssh:%h:"))))
              (require 'tramp)
              (tramp-mode 1)))
```

When I try:

/ssh:user@hostname.com|sudo:hostname

or:

/sudo:hostname.com

and many, many other combinations . . .

. . . the minute I type the colon after 'sudo' in any syntax configuration it immediately throws an error stating that sudo can only be used locally.

BONUS QUESTION: can I use Tramp to first log into a remote server as myself and sudo to another generic sudo userid there after? Like ssh:my_userid@remote_host.com|sudo:generic_userid@remost_host.com:/path/to/file

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's probably worth rewriting this question to include the error (please always include the *actual* error verbatim in your questions), and to emphasise (for future readers) that it's about the combination of Helm and Tramp. Randy Morris' comment to the accepted answer could be highlighted as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget setting `tramp-default-proxies-alist` for the time being. Just open `C-x C-f /ssh:user@hostname.com|sudo:hostname.com:`. I also don't understand what setting `tramp-mode` shall be good for.

BONUS ANSWER: yes. Your example needs a leading `/`, 'tho.

Comment: Yeah, I added those configs gleaned from other posts to see if that made any difference (it didn't). Without the config I get this when hitting the colon after sudo -- 'Error running timer: (error "in 'Find Files' source: 'helm-find-files-get-candidates' (user-error \"Host name must not match method \\\"sudo \\\"\")")

Comment: That doesn't sound like a Tramp error. Start with `emacs -Q` and try to open a remote file as proposed - it shall work. Then you could activate your `~/.emacs` successively, in order to see which other package is in the way. The error message you quote indicates, that helm.el might be the candidate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Helm was the problem. It works when I disable Helm. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks also for the answer to the bonus question, which also worked!!

Comment: @Kawili-wili helm doesn't support the pipe (`|`) syntax that tramp can use.  See https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/981

Comment: @RandyMorris: Yes, I saw that page. None of the suggested workarounds seemed to work for me though.